# Conditional data binding in Alloy

Tags: appcelerator

Alloy supports data binding with collections and single models.

How can I conditionally style view elements based on models attribute value?

eg: if model.status = 'open' I want to give red background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking ListView as an example.

Markup:

```
<ListSection dataCollection="books" dataTransform="doTransform">
    <ListItem title:text="{title}" subtitle:text="{subtitle}" itemId="{id}" backgroundColor="{backgroundColor}" />
</ListSection>
```

Controller:

```
function doTransform(model){
    var transform = model.toJSON();
    transform.backgroundColor = transform.status=="open"?"red":"white";
    return transform;
}
```

[Docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Data_Binding-section-36739592_AlloyDataBinding-CollectionExample)